# Distinct list on date but select most complete object to keep

Tags: c#

Is it possible in C# to distinct a list on DateTime but select the most filled/complete object for this date?

Say I have these etries in the list on 2014-01-01:

```
**date        | value | pressure | temp  | message**
  2014-01-01  |  200  |          |  25   | Active alarm on sensor 1
  2014-01-01  |  200  |          |  25   |
  2014-01-01  |  200  |  1000    |  25   | Active alarm on sensor 1
  2014-01-01  |       |  1000    |  25   | Active alarm on sensor 1
```

This is a table with a lot of colums. I do not know what is filled and what's not, I just want the most complete one.

How is this done in C# because a lot of the times it gets the first one it sees?

Note the list is a collection with a date range that can be over a month with a lot of doubles.

Edit:

This is the function I use to distinct the list.

```
        private static List<Validated_Output> getDistinct(List<Validated_Output>        validated)
    {
        // Delete double entries in the collection
        var DistinctItems = validated
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Vd_summertime, x.TimeStamp })
            .Select(y => y.First()).ToList();

        return DistinctItems;
    }
```

I select on Timestamp and DST because a timestamp can occur twice during tranition from summer to winter and vice versa.

The query is on a list populated from a lot of header/detail data from another table. I write to the database after I distinct on this list.

Comment: So you basically want to fetch the 3rd row in this case, since the 3rd detail is complete?

Comment: Show us the code you are using to query that table

Comment: Is this a sql question? If so, what's your rdbms? Also show your schema and what you've tried.

Comment: `Enumerable.OrderBy` for linq to objects can take an implementation of an `IComparer`, one of which could easily be created to sort "more populated" items from less populated items, then simply `.First()`

Comment: I have updated the question. I use a linq query on a c# list. the data is not saved to the database (MSSQL) till after this operation.

Comment: @user3017868: it's still not clear, what specifies the _the most complete one_? Why do you show now properties `Vd_summertime`and `TimeStamp` that are not in your sample list?

Comment: Well in the original question i simplified the table a little. I indeed need the third one in the example. the one with the most populated fields. I am now checking out how IComparer works. I am fairly new to .net and c#.

Comment: What I would suggest is that you create some metric to determine how complete a row is as a score from 0 to some number. This could be as simple as a count of how many fields have content or you could weight the fields so that field A being present is preferable to field B, etc. You should have this in your head already for the question to make sense. Once you have that you can group as you already do and then sort the groups based on that metric before selcting the first. I've noticed having typed that that this is basically what Adam suggested 10 minutes ago but with more words. ;-)

Comment: Yes as i said I was looking into Icomparer as Adam suggested. I think this is what I need. Thank you for the more indept view. When I have it figured out i will post the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Distinct will not be able to order the collisions it encounters so as you said the best way to manage what you need is to first group on the DateTime property then order each group according to some property and select the first one.

The OrderBy must take into account the "filling factor" of a Validated_Output. You can calculate this "filling factor" by using a score calculated based on how many properties are significant in a Validated_Output. Such a method can be wrapped in a Scored_Validated_Output class:

```
public class Scored_Validated_Output {
    public Validated_Output ValidatedOutput {get;set;}
    public int Score {get;set;}
    public Scored_Validated_Output(Validated_Output validatedOutput) {
        ValidatedOutput = validatedOutput;
        Score = score(ValidatedOutput);
    }
    public int score(Validated_Output vo) {
        var score = 0;
        score += vo.value > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        // scoring rules left to your imagination
        // you may want to push forward older items, etc
        return score;
    }
}
```

Then your getDistinct method would become:

```
private static List<Validated_Output> getDistinct(List<Validated_Output> validated)
{
     var DistinctItems = validated
        .GroupBy(x => x.Date) // we group the Validated_Output by date
        .Select(g => 
            g.Select(vo => new Scored_Validated_Output(vo)) // in each group we score the Validated_Outputs
            .OrderByDescending(svo => svo.Score) // we order them by descending score
            .First() // keep only the first one (ie the highest score)
            .ValidatedOutput ) // and resolve it back to Validated_Output
        .ToList();

    return DistinctItems;
}
```

Hope this helps